# Running Update Qry in VBA Based on a Query Value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to run an Update Query in VBA and am at a lost as to what I'm supposed to write for the code. I'm running a query to find the most recent date from a table. That query works fine. Now I want to run an update query to update another table's date field to equal to the date that was queried. Here is what I have:

```
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim newdate1

'selects datadate 1
Date1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Max(Date1_Event) from TBL_Event WHERE ID = '" & [Forms]![FRM_Main]![ID] & "'")(0)

'update datadate 1
newdate1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Update Tbl_Name set CollectionDate = DataDate1 WHERE PID = '" & [Forms]![FRM_Main]![ID] & "'")(0)
```

Is there a way to run an update query like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action queries (`DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT INTO`) are to be executed (`CurrentDb.Execute`) while `SELECT` queries are to be opened as recordsets (`CurrentDb.OpenRecordset`).

Additionally, consider using parameterization to avoid any need of quote enclosure or string concatenation in query. And here the max date is calculated with domain aggregate, `DMax()`, instead of opening another query.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdef As Querydef

' PREPARE SQL STATEMENT
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [MaxDateParam] Date, [FormIDParam] Long;" _
           & "UPDATE Tbl_Name SET CollectionDate = [MaxDateParam]" _
           & " WHERE PID = [FormIDParam];"

' BUILD TEMP QUERY
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

' BIND PARAMETERS
qdef!MaxDateParam = DMax("Date1_Event", "TBL_Event", "ID=" & [Forms]![FRM_Main]![ID])
qdef!FormIDParam = [Forms]![FRM_Main]![ID]

' EXECUTE ACTION
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Though above may look unusual and slightly more lines. Don't be intimidated and run for the easy 1-2 lines. Parameterization is a programming industry best practice not just in VBA but across all general purpose languages that run dynamic SQL queries using values from user input.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been self-teaching myself a lot of Access/VBA so I  usually don't even know where to start (I have very little/no coding experience...learning it as i go along). do you know of any resources for learning SQL/querying within VBA?

Comment: Also, for the [MaxDateParam], is there a way to tweak the date it's pulling? I figured out that I'll need to tweak the query a little bit (I don't necessarily want the max date. My table has a bunch of entries that records dates, so I want the most recent date that was recorded. For example, I might have a date of 7/1/2017 recorded on 6/1/2017. But if I record a date of 6/15/2017 recorded on 6/5/2017, I want it to update to the date that was recorded on 6/5/2017.)

Comment: Try using the [DLast()](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlast.php) domain aggregate which returns last saved value by criteria. But it also sounds like you want to have a *DateCreated* with default `=Now()` or *DateModified* field where a save function on form updates this field. This would be another SO question.

Comment: Great thank you. I ended up combining my original method of writing a SQL query and set the value of that query to the MaxDateParam so I'd be able to modify the query if I needed to. Thank you. This was very helpful

Comment: Consider a saved query. No need to open a recordset and queries can read form controls without quotes. You would then need a `DLookup` on query. And glad I could help. Please accept answer (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.

Comment: Is there a pro to using a saved query/dlookup over my method of opening a recordset?

Comment: Probably more to do with preference, but opening a recordset for one value seem like too much overhead. Also, saved queries are more efficient than VBA string queries as the Access database engine saves best execution plan and cannot do so if called on the fly in VBA. In fact, the prepared statement here can be a saved query and then change: `Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")`